# Gulp - Get CSS file matching HTML file name

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to create a Gulp script with a very specific piece of functionality and I don't know where to begin. Basically, I want it to include and inline the CSS from a Less file with the same filename as the HTML file. So slide1.html would only pull in the CSS from slide1.less, and slide2.html would only pull in the CSS from slide2.less. Is this possible in Gulp?